# How to read crashed bug logs from apple review team but not my device

Tags: ios, c, object

I got crashed bug logs from Review Team, i tried to reproduce but can't on my device. I don't know where i can start.

```
Incident Identifier: F1E7FB74-9137-4A5C-862B-E6B37986EE06
CrashReporter Key:   64fa1b8d2b4ec9de527f4904264fa949d3791ecb
Hardware Model:      xxx

Identifier:          com.nguyenthuan.chuctet
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-02-02 10:26:19.926 -0800
Launch Time:         2015-02-02 10:26:14.116 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.1.3 (12B466)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1835a659c 0x1942000e4 0x18849129c 0x188053630 0x1880520e0 0x187dd7564 0x187d48e78 0x18355ea50 0x18355b9dc 0x18355bdbc 0x1834890a4 0x18c60f5a4 0x187dbaaa4 0x1000ed690 0x19486ea08)
```

Comment: ref log file: http://a861.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/a5/d0/37/a5d03720-c718-8367-c8b6-17f21b773450/temp..abalarxm.crash?downloadKey3=1423144734_6939b9a48a7dcb054a2161dc8af777b8

Comment: Looks like a webview memory pressure issue.

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report.

Comment: Apple Review Team said me: they click on "share" button in my app and app is crashed. But I used   UIActivity default of iOS. Also checked on my device too, no crash. I don't use webview in my app